# How can I keep a file private on a public GitLab repository?

Tags: gitlab, token, privacy

I'm working on a Java app that uses multiple APIs and would like to keep the API tokens out of the public GitLab repository. The app is packaged and deployed to a remote server and I don't know how to make the tokens available without including them in the GitLab repository otherwise.

Is there a way I can restrict the viewing of a file (or part of it) to sort of "redact" these tokens? Or should I go about it a different way?

Comment: I'd inject tokens with environment variables which can be configured via `Project Settings -> Variables`, Variables are not visible for public project.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put API keys in your repo. Inject them into your *use* of the repo via environment variables which are maintained by your deployment system. If you deployment system doesn't have that ability, you probably need to change it. It doesn't need to be too complicated - for example change it to deploying your code from git, then copying a `.env` file into place separately. If your deployment mechanism *only* lets you use git repos, you could put your env vars into a separate repo that is kept private.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation with injecting `google-services.json` file into an Android application. Long story short we have multiple environments our app targets, and the production environment file must, somehow, reside in the build pipelines (either, committed or something).

As pointed by the previous response having this information committed in the main repo is not ideal. Developers could accidentally use the production environment while testing for example.

## How we solved this

First, documentation. All those files (`google-services.json` and similar others) are ignored in git and the developer documentation states you must add your own.

Second, the CI build pipelines. We are also using GitLab, and we store those files as base64 encoded strings in CI variables, controlling then access to those variables via the protected tags/branches mechanism GitLab offers.

### Serializing the files

There are two steps involved in here. First serialize an actual file in base64. Second, de-serialize the file from base64 into its appropriate location.

`base64 --wraps=0 google-services.json` (wraps option prevents line wrapping if done in console directly.). Then store the output in a GitLab CI variable.

In the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file do the inverse to inject the file.

`echo $VAR_NAME | base64 -d > where/you/need/the/file`.

You then control the appropriate environment to use via the `$VAR_NAME` variable.

An example of this an be found at https://gitlab.com/snippets/1926611. This case is for an `xml` file with the Google Maps API key, but the process is identical.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the snippet! I have a better understanding of environment variables now but I'm still not too sure how they would work locally. Do your project devs still need a local copy of the encoded file to make it work for them?

Comment: Yes and no. Devs must have their own versions of the files locally without any encoding. The base64 encoding bit is entirely a mechanism to store files contents in environment variable strings, they are decoded and place in the filesystem by th CI pipeline before calling build routines. (I should add that since you've done this, GitLab add a variable of type file, we haven't looked into it.)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable in you GitLab project settings. The variable can be used in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

For example,

1. create a variable named `GOOGLE_SERVICE_JSON` and set the value to the base64 format of the file content. You can get it by command `base64 google-services.json`
2. update your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, decode the `GOOGLE_SERVICE_JSON` value to `google-services.json` file like this

```
assembleDebug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo ${GOOGLE_SERVICE_JSON} | base64 -d > app/google-services.json
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/
```

You can also use this method to encode the keystore file to a variant and decode it to a file in pipeline build.

Here is a full example

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "28"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "28.0.3"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS:   "6609375_latest"

before_script:
  - echo ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK ${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
  - echo ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS ${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}
  - echo ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS ${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}.zip
  - unzip -d android-sdk-linux android-sdk.zip
  - export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export SDK_MANAGER="${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}"
  - echo y | ${SDK_MANAGER} "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
  - echo y | ${SDK_MANAGER} "platform-tools" >/dev/null
  - echo y | ${SDK_MANAGER} "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" >/dev/null
  - export PATH=$PATH:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/platform-tools/
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  # temporarily disable checking for EPIPE error and use yes to accept all licenses
  - set +o pipefail
  - echo y | ${SDK_MANAGER} --licenses
  - set -o pipefail

stages:
  - build

assembleDebug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo ${GOOGLE_SERVICE_JSON} | base64 -d > app/google-services.json
    - echo ${KEY_STORE_PROP} | base64 -d > app/keystore.properties
    - echo ${STORE_FILE} | base64 -d > app/keystore.jks
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/

assembleRelease:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo ${GOOGLE_SERVICE_JSON} | base64 -d > app/google-services.json
    - echo ${KEY_STORE_PROP} | base64 -d > app/keystore.properties
    - echo ${STORE_FILE} | base64 -d > app/keystore.jks
    - ./gradlew assembleRelease
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/
```